# How to get a list of latest apps released on Play Store sorted by date?

Tags: google-play-store

Is there any way to get a list of recently released apps on Google Play Store sorted according to date added?

Answer (score 1):

**ShivamSoni**

As **google play store** have **daily adds New  Updates** of Apps of thousand/lakhs/millions  of new versions all of them are new for Play store .

But still **I searched and founded** links for  **new releases** sections for you in **play store website** options.  I am **sharing below links** of **website** of new releases  and option to search apps latest releases apps category wise. But i dont think its possible to sort all apps list date wise launch option in app or website.

https://play.google.com/store/apps/new?hl=en

https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/cluster?clp=Si8KKQojcHJvbW90aW9uXzMwMDA3OTJfbmV3X3JlbGVhc2VzX2FwcHMQBxgDOgIIAQ%3D%3D:S:ANO1ljKj5O4&gsr=CjFKLwopCiNwcm9tb3Rpb25fMzAwMDc5Ml9uZXdfcmVsZWFzZXNfYXBwcxAHGAM6AggB:S:ANO1ljILDUU&hl=en

In **Google Play store App version 19.3.36** there are **tabs** named **"for you, Top Charts,  Categories....."** tabs of at **very last** there is a tab in last  **"Early Access"** which  shows latest to be launched beta developing Apps and  games.

[image: Google play store Early access photo]

**There are  many 3rd party apps** that you can utilizes to sort and easy your work  about **one of popular one i searched**   is called **AppBrain App Market**, and can be **downloaded for free** via **Google Play** (see the link at the below). **The best way to find new apps in Google Play.**

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps&referrer=utm_source%3Dappbrain%26utm_medium%3Dappbrain_web%26utm_campaign%3Dappbrain_web

**According to appbrain website link says product details says**

https://www.appbrain.com/app/appbrain-app-market/com.appspot.swisscodemonkeys.apps

> **Description**
>
> The best way to find new apps in Google Play (Android market).
>
> Make the Android market usable, and find your next favorite app, live wallpaper or widget:
>   - App recommendations
>   - New and hot apps of the day
>   - Find top Android apps with a price drop
>   - Share your best apps (eg twitter/facebook)
>   - Tracks market update: notifies of updates available
>   - Fast uninstaller
>   - Browse "my apps" on www.appbrain.com and install apps with a sync instead of barcode scanner
>   - Keep your list of installed apps as a backup on AppBrain.com
>
> AppBrain is the best way to discover top Android apps in the Android market and to manage your apps. The recommended apps helper provides recommendations based on what you already use. We also have recommended games. It does not work with the Amazon app store.
>
> The manage apps is like a killer file explorer / task manager for your already installed apps:
>   - Start app, Quick uninstaller, share to Facebook
>   - Fast sync widget to access AppBrain from the desktop and backup your apps to the cloud
>   - app2sd functionality to move apps to sd (app 2 sd)
>   - Find market update: notifies you of any updates available
>
> Discover cool apps and top games in the Android market:
>   - sort by hot apps today, hot apps this week, highest rated apps, price drops etc
>   - Filter apps by free apps, paid apps, price reduced apps, app2sd enabled apps, new apps
>   - Fast search over the entire Android market
>   - Unlike applanet or black market, these are only legal apps.
>
> AppBrain is the best app market and app discovery tool for Android apps from the Android Market. It allows you to easily find the best apps in the Market, the free apps and downloads, the price drops, live wallpaper, widgets and much more.

Hope this app will help you  any further  option i will get  i will update in the answer.

> Hope my **answer suggestions helped you** if any thing helped you out from your search or my or others help do tell me what **helped you in comments** for my knowledge. if any **doubts or further clarification** feel free to ask and if worked do **not forget  to accept and vote for the answer**